# Browser livarage cache failed on js ,css and png assets on apache

Tags: cache, ubuntu-16.04, apache2, http-headers

I am trying to enable browser leverage caching for my angular5 application. Files serve with apache

Here is the configuration I've added in the `vhost`

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript  "access 1 week"
  ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
  </filesmatch>
</IfModule>
```

But I am testing my website with https://tools.pingdom.com/ I am getting  cache failed error message for the `.js ,.css and .png` assets.

> The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime.
>   Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the
>   following resources:

**UPDATE**

Header for `.js`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 17 Aug 2018 09:44:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Aug 2018 11:25:11 GMT
ETag: "172da-5738bb238dfbb-gzip"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=631138519; includeSubDomains
Content-Length: 32241
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Comment: What are the response headers you get when requesting one of those resources?   Add them to your question.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille updated  my question

Comment: Where's the Cache-Control header?  Expires missing too.  Wrong vhost?  mod_expires and mod_headers not loaded.

Comment: mod_expires already loaded  `Module headers already enabled`,vhost is proper

Comment: However, I can able to see `from memory cache`  in the status code in chrome

Comment: Did you get the headers in your question from an other browser?  Does chrome show a 304 status  (not modified) ?

Comment: Do you have a cache in front of your Apache?

Comment: There is no cache in front of apache but there is https redirection present ,do i need to add all configurations to SSL vhost(443)?

Comment: If you want those rules to apply when using HTTPS, of course.  That's why I asked "wrong vhost?"